# django: Does `unique=True` prevent `IntegrityError`?

Tags: python, django

I realized that when I have a simple model:

```
class Category(models.Model):
    name  = models.CharField(max_length=128, unique=True)
    views = models.IntegerField(default=0)
    likes = models.IntegerField(default=0)
```

the modifier `unique=True` has the effect that when I add a category to the database (via an HTML form) which has a name of an instance already present in the database, the application will not crash.
Instead, I get access to `form.errors` which I can print to the page or to the terminal.
If I omit `unique=True` and I try to add a category to the database with a name that already exists, I get an `IntegrityError` and my application crashes.

So it seems to me that defining `unique=True` is pretty important for the behaviour of the application. I guess then there must be other model attributes which are equally importa

In the django documentation, where can I read about this and if there are other such attributes?

Comment: I don't see why django should handle the `name` column special. What's the exact error that you get when you omit `unique=True`? Are you connecting to an existing database which someone else created or are you letting django create the database tables for you?

Comment: I get an `IntegrityError`, `column name is not unique`. The database is created by myself and I use `syncdb` whenever I switch between using or omitting `unique=True`, just fyi.

Comment: "I use syncdb whenever I switch" - that is pointless, as syncdb does not update existing tables.

Comment: Ok, i guess i don't understand what it's needed for. I thought I should do that whenever I change something to the model.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

First of all, you created the model using the unique constraint, so the database already has the unique constraint.Something like (for MySQL):

```
CONSTRAINT myapp_category UNIQUE (name)
```

Now, you are probably using a `ModelForm`, which picks this attribute `unique=True`, and applies that validation. So, you can catch the errors via `form.errors` and handle it gracefully.

When you remove the attribute, the database still has the constraint, but the `ModelForm` does not perform that validation for you, hence the `IntegrityError`

So, to answer your question - `unique=True` does help prevent raising of an exception when you use it in the context of a `ModelForm`, or you would have to handle it yourself to make it fail gracefully.

To remove the `unique` constraint from the database, you would have to use a migration tool like `south`

Comment: I guess the default behavior of the database including an `unique` constraint makes sense, so I can live with that. Understanding what's happening under the hood is my motivation for asking this question. And your exactly pointing to what I'm wondering about: How do I catch the exception when I dont use `unique=True`? I tried all kinds of combinations of importing various django modules but I cant seem to find where the `IntegrityError` exception is defined.

Comment: You can handle it by overriding the `clean` method of the form to see if the unique constraint is being violated. If it is, raise a `ValidationError`

Comment: Do I need to import something such that I can catch a `ValidationError`?

Comment: `from django.core.exceptions import ValidationError`  If that is what you are asking. To actually raise the error - just do `if Category.objects.filter(name=name).exists(): raise ValidationError`

Answer (score 1):

My guess is that you have a database model which has a `UNIQUE` constraint on the `name` column. If you try to insert two rows with the same name, then the database (via the database driver) will throw an `IntegrityError`. This happens completely independent of django.

django then has a model how to build forms. If you omit the `unique=True`, django assumes that the column in the database isn't unique and doesn't add the necessary checks in the form validation step.

So you basically have a config mismatch between your form and your database.

Solutions:

- Make sure the constraints for forms and database columns are always the same
- Write your own, custom validation rules (see the django documentation).

Alternatively: Write code that gets unique constraints from the database and then, when you create a form, check that the necessary attributes are set to avoid this error.